# Is there a way, to include a method into a responsive step on a form layout

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, form-layout

Does anyone know a way to include a method into a responsive step, for example when (in the code below) the window is resized to the point where the formlayout is less than the specified value at 1010px, the layout changes itself to 1 column like in the first responsive step, but what i also want during this switch between responsivesteps, is a couple lines of my own code, like a custom method i could include and write whatever i want in it, that triggers when the formlayout width is below 1010px.

```
formLayout.setResponsiveSteps(
                new FormLayout.ResponsiveStep("0", 1, FormLayout.ResponsiveStep.LabelsPosition.TOP),
                new FormLayout.ResponsiveStep("1010px", 2));
```

Edit : Vaadin 13.0.4 flow is what im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. But there is a more generic `BrowserWindowResizeEvent`, which you can listen to by adding listener via `Page` class using `addBrowserWindowResizeListener(BrowserWindowResizeListener resizeListener)`, and achieve probably the thing you are looking for.

Comment: ye its kinda doing what i want, some other issue with the code im trying to use, but i'll figure it out, thank you for the help, i appreciate it

Comment: follow up question if you maybe see this, do you have any idea how to get the width of any component in pixels? getWidth method just returns null always, and SizeReporter doesnt work with flow components

Comment: There is no API for that either yet. But you can do it by calling javascript that gets the elements offsetwidth and offsetheight and which calls client callable that processes the data sent by client. See the principle here: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17352478/how-to-get-results-from-page-executejavascript